# iOS widgetkit click respective index issue

Tags: ios, widgetkit

How to click respective widget kit and get respective widgetkit index and model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9qza.jpg)

How to click respective widget kit and get respective widgetkit index and model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.